# How does this Array.apply method works?

Tags: javascript

I understand you can pass an array to `Function.prototype.apply` but recently I've come across this code (it was written as a good way to create an array with `undefined` values as opposed to empty slots or holes);

```
var a = Array.apply( null, { length: 3 } );
```

I can't understand how this code works starting with the second argument. Is there another syntax that could be used to make it more understandable what's going on? What's going on when we pass an actual object to `apply` as opposed to an array? Can we somehow translate this object to an array to get this result? I've tried many things to do this, but without success.

Comment: It is the same as `new Array(3)`

Comment: no it isn't, not exactly

Comment: @JaromandaX: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.1

Comment: @Microfed - why is that directed at me?

Comment: @JaromandaX: because it says that Array() and new Array() returns equal results. :)

Comment: yes ... that has zero to do with the question, the code in the question does **not** produce the same result as new Array(3) or Array(3)

Comment: @JaromandaX — http://jsbin.com/jisima/2/edit?js,console — It seems to create the same result for all practical intents and purposes. The approach taken is very different, so saying that "it is the same" isn't very helpful in terms of answer the question though.

Comment: @Quentin - the output on jsbin doesn't match what I see on a genuine console ... `Array(3)` and `new Array(3)` produces three empty slots, the code in the question produces three populated slots ... that's not "the same", if you wanr/need a sparse array

Comment: @JaromandaX: it seems you're right: https://jsbin.com/gaguwacavi/edit?js,console

Comment: `Array(3)` is 50 times faster than the code in the question. In firefox, the code in the question is limited to `length:500000` - in chrome, the limit seems to be 124492 ... there's more difference than similarity between the two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, that is just horrible.

So, when you call `Array` as a function, it doesn't really care what `this` is so you can tell it that `this` is `null`.

The second argument for `apply` is *an array-like object* which gives the list of arguments.

If you had `[0, 0, 0]` then that would be **like** this object:

```
{
    0: 0,
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    length: 3
}
```

… because arrays get a length property which equals the value of their highest index. A real array would get other properties from the prototype, but we (and `apply`, and `Array`) don't care about them.

The arguments you pass to `Array` become its initial values.

Now, it seems that (internally) `Array` checks the `length` of its `arguments` and then sets its internal values using something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    internal_array_values.push(arguments[0])
}
```

And if you have an object which consists solely of `{ length: 3 }` it is going to get `undefined` as the value of each of those three arguments giving you `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`.

Comment: `apple` -> `apply`. Sorry, can't fix it myself

Answer (score 1):

http://www.2ality.com/2012/07/apply-tricks.html

With `apply` and `Array` (which can be used as either a function or a constructor), you can turn holes into undefined elements:

```
 Array.apply(null, ["a",,"b"])
  // [ 'a', undefined, 'b' ]
```